# How do I duplicate an Adwords ad and direct it to a different landing page?

Tags: google-ads

I have a selection of ads that I want duplicate. They are all in the same adgroup. After duplication I simply want to change the landing page of the newly created ads. How would I do this in the Adwords interface or in the Adwords editor? When I check the ads with Adwords editor after duplication and changing the final url the ads are removed because they're all marked as duplicates. How would I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Are these the instructions you're following? https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3400898?hl=en

These instructions have worked successfully for us even if the changes are minimal.

Comment: A link only answer is not high quality.  It would be better to include the main points in your answer here.   Links can change or go bad.  It is also not good user experience to force a click to get the answer.